# How to nondimensionalize a first-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble nondimensionalizing this first-order differential equation:

$\dot x=rx-hx^2+q$, where $\dot x= \frac{dx}{dt}$. I'm assuming $r,h,q$ have different units.

I first tried $\tau=t/t_0$ and $A=x/x_0$. Then I got $\frac{dAx_0}{d\tau t_0}=rAx_0-hA^2x_0^2+q$. But I am not really sure where to go from there.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: To **solve** the ODE, I recommend using "natural" units: Take $1/r$ as your unit of time and $r/h$ as your unit of length, then the ODE reduces to $x=x-x^2+q$.

Comment: Hello Filippo, is the ‘x’ on the left hand side supposed to be x with a dot over it?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sorry

Comment: Btw, $\dot x=x-x^2+q$ is non-dimensional. I made the typical abuse of notation of using the same symbol for the physical quantity $q$ and its value with respect to a specific choice of units.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I should have written $\dot x=x-x^2+Q$, where $Q$ equals the real number $qh/r^2$, the value of the velocity $q$ with respect to our choice of units

Answer (score 0):

- Here is what I consider the usual approach: You should convince yourself that solving your ODE for a specific choice of units gives you the solution for any choice of units: Think about how the function $x$ and the numbers $r,h,q$ are postulated to transform under a change of units. In particular, it suffices to solve the ODE for the case $h=r=1$. This can be interpreted as choosing $1/r$ as unit of time and $r/h$ as unit of length.
- I do not think that $x$ can be considered a function into the set of lengths, since the numerical value of a length with respect to some unit is always a non-negative number. For example, $|x|$ can be considered a physical quantity - the distance to the origin. The fact that $x$ also takes negative values suggests that $x$ is a vector quantity. See the comments for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Physical quantities can be negative for sure, typically position with respect to some coordinate system. Or even more "real" quantities like pressure or electrostatic potential and charge. Or more precisely function describing physical quantities can be negative which should be the relevant thing here.

Comment: @Korf Thank you for the comment. I have slightly edited the second point. I'd say that the reason "position" and "pressure" take negative values is that they are actually vector quantities (identified with a physical quantity **and** a direction) and in 1-dimensional problems, we can simply choose an (arbitrary) orientation and represent them by real numbers.

Comment: @Korf For example, if we assume that space is a 1-dim. euclidean space, we can choose an origin to identify "position" with a vector. The norm of the vector - not the vector itlself - then is a length.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
Can use physical dimensions to units:

$$ x \to m \text { meter linear } $$
$$ r x \to \omega x ; \quad r\to \text{frequency or angular velocity}$$
$$ q\to v \text{  velocity}$$
$$ h= \frac{L}{T L^2} \to \omega/ m .$$